# Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Dossier::$program has no effect

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Good Day I have this code on backend (trying to update this value in MONGO)
http://prntscr.com/j03gh4

```
$dossier=Dossier::where('_id',(int)$request->input('dossier_id'))->first();
//var_dump($request->input('value'));
$dossier->program[$request->input('program')]['cities']
 [$request->input('city')]['services']
 [$request->input('service')][$request->input('name')]=$request->input('value');
$dossier->save();
```

But I receive this Exception
http://prntscr.com/j03h0s

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Dossier::$program has no effect

What have I do to repair this situation?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am sorry But If you know Why this Exception present plese explaine. I dont understand Thats why I am asking. And I just ask for a help.Why Are you so prim & smug?

Comment: Is it too hard for you to include the exception message in the question? Do you really need to direct u to 3rd party services? And also, say 5 years from now when someone has the same problem and finds this question, do you really trust that 3rd party service to still have your screenshot stored?

Comment: Ok I publish the Exception message Just Screen gives all the picture : )

Comment: God Bless StackOverflow : )

Comment: Adding the exception message ensures that if someone googles "mongo indicrect modification has no effect" this question will pop up because it will be indexed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that calling `$dossier->program` does not actually access the property directly in Eloquent type models but rather calls a `__get` method.

That get method does not return a reference to the property. What you should do is grab the original property, modify it and then put it back:

```
$dossier=Dossier::where('_id',(int)$request->input('dossier_id'))->first();
$originalProgram = $dossier->program;
$originalProgram[$request->input('program')]['cities'][$request->input('city')]['services'][$request->input('service')][$request->input('name')]=$request->input('value');
$dossier->program = $originalProgram;
$dossier->save();
```

Comment: Thank You very much mister Apokrifos :)

Comment: Great explanation ever! Thanks a lot!